# The existence of an optimal distributed control problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, oc.optimization-and-control

Consider $\Omega$ as a bounded interval of $\mathbb{R}$, and let $y\in L^{\infty}(\Omega \times (0,T))$ be a mild solution of the following parabolic partial differential equation:
\begin{equation}\label{e1}
\begin{cases}
    \dot y(x,t)= y_{xx}(x,t)+ u(x,t)y(x,t) \quad 
    \text{in} \  \Omega \times (0,T),    \\
    y=0 \ \text{on} \     \Gamma \times (0,T), \\  y(0)=y_0 \ \text{in} \ \Omega
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}
where $u\in L^2(\Omega \times (0,T))$ is a given function. The objective is to establish the existence of an optimal control $u^*\in L^2(\Omega \times (0,T))$.

To prove the existence of an optimal control, we consider a sequence of functions $u_n$ that weakly converges to $u^*$, and we let $y_n$ and $y^*$ be the solutions of the equation above corresponding to $u_n$ and $u^*$, respectively.

**My question is:**  How to demonstrate that $y^n$ converges to $y^*$ in the $L^2$ norm?

Comment: Note that optimality does not play a role in your question. You do not even formulate an optimality criterion. What you are really asking is whether the map $u\mapsto y$ is weak-norm continuous. This is an exercise, is it not? Please consider asking on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. You are correct that the original question does not explicitly state an optimality criterion, and that the goal is to establish the weak-norm continuity of the map $u \mapsto y$.